# Sort value issue on categorical column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to take a categorical column, group by individual type and then sum each type
I am using Python code and its result is what I want

```
data2 = data.groupby(['service_type']).sum().unstack()
popular_ser2 = data2.sort_values(ascending = False).head(10).droplevel(0)
popular_ser2
```

[image: my expected result]

I would like to confirm whether my code is logic due to the need of unstack and droplevel that is uncommon to see when using groupby and sort value.

Comment: Well, did the code produce the right output? Does it consistently produce the right output when you give it other, more difficult test cases (but ones you're still able to verify by hand, or have the correct answer written out to be checked automatically)? Does the code make sense *to you*? Questions about how best to write the code for understanding are off topic here; you might try https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  yes, the picture is what I am expecting. Because rarely using Groupby with droplevel so I am here to check with you guy. I have posted on Stack Exchange but my post is pending and repost need 40 minutes later.